# Eliminate Sliver Polygons QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, polygon, slivers, eliminate

I'm a regular user of the `'Eliminate Sliver Polygons'` tool in QGIS. I've just switched from 2.18 to 3.4.4 and the `'Eliminate Sliver Polygons'` tool isn't available. Has it been removed from this version? Are there any alternatives available?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In QGIS 3.4, it is under `Processing toolbox -> Vector geometry` with a new name `Eliminate Selected Polygons`

[image]

There is additional option is to eliminate based on the `Smallest polygon area` in addition to the previously available options which are `Largest polygon area` and `Largest common boundary`

Comment: Buffer and dissolve might also help in some cases where the exact boundaries are not that important.

Comment: This says "This algorithm *combines* selected polygons of the input layer with certain *adjacent* polygons by erasing their common boundary." but slivers polygons are often to be completely removed. Is this also possible?

Comment: @bugmenot123 Sorry, I did not quite understand your question. What do you want to do? If you want to remove the sliver completely, you need to select those polygons, then select the suitable criteria: `Smallest polygon area`, `Largest polygon area`, or `Largest common boundary` that should be used to remove those polygons. You need to do some testing to decide which criterion is the best for your case.

Comment: Consider sliver polygons like the ones shown in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229602/deleting-sliver-polygons-after-difference-operation-in-qgis , how could those be eliminated by this tool? Sorry if this is offtopic, I think they question here was answered by you (new name of the existing tool that OP was searching for).

Comment: @bugmenot123 For the example you showed in that link, I don’t think the `Eliminate Selected Polygons` tool can work. If you look at this specific case, the polygons are not contained by other polygon and there is no shared boundary between the polygons except for few of them. They are mostly separated polygon (islands) and the tool cannot eliminate those polygons for this specific example.