# Merging polygons with adjacent polygons using QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge, generalization

I am using QGIS (version: 3.28) and I am looking for a way for an automatic spatial generalization of polygons:

1. Step: Merge adjacent polygons of same class (e.g. class "Grünfläche")
2. Step: Polygons of class "Grünfläche" that are smaller then e.g. 0.3 ha should be merged with the adjacent polygon of another class, that has the longest "common boarder" with that polygon "Grünfläche". In other words: If a small polygon "Grünfläche" has a longer boarder with polygon of class "Landwirtschaft" and a shorter border with the polygon "Siedlung" --> the polygon "Grünfläche" should become "Landwirtschaft" and merge with the adjacent polygon "Landwirtschaft"

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [Eliminate Selected Polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/336133/63384).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: You might want to post some sample data

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Run **Dissolve**, using Class as the Dissolve field, and Keep disjoint features separate flag checked.

Step 2a: Use Field Calculator to add an Area field, to get the area in hectares.

Step 2b: Select all polygons with Area < 0.3 ha using **Select by expression**.

Step 2c: Use **Eliminate selected polygons** with Largest Common Boundary as the merge criterion.